# Populate web form edit page C# ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to select a single row on a gridview and have that selection take me to a separate edit page with the data populated. I have the idea of using a session variable to hold the row id and then retrieving the data on page load and populating the text boxes. My question is whether or not this is the best method to go about doing this? I would prefer to not use the inline edit option in gridview as I have too many columns that would require scrolling horizontally. Here is my page load method using the session variable:

```
  if (Session["editID"] != null)
        {
            dbCRUD db = new dbCRUD();
            Recipe editRecipe = new Recipe();

            var id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["editID"]);
            Session.Remove("editID");


            editRecipe = db.SelectRecord(id);
            addName.Text = editRecipe.Name;
        }
```

Here is the SelectRecord method that is used to retrieve the row:

```
 public Recipe SelectRecord(int id)
    {
        Recipe returnedResult = new Recipe();

            var dbConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            var dbCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.selectRecipe", dbConn);


            dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;


            dbConn.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.HasRows) 
            { 
                while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        returnedResult.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                    }
            }

            dbConn.Close();

            return returnedResult;
      }
```

I'm probably not utilizing the SQLDataReader appropriately, but my result is no data in the reader therefore no returned data when calling the method. Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: The record returned does have multiple columns, but I'm only assigning the name value to test the functionality.

Comment: Are you getting to the 'while(reader.Read())' part? In other words are you returning any rows?

Comment: Yes, at least I know that while(reader.HasRows) is true so I assume I'm at least in that loop, but then the program actually hangs and will not process further. It is a remote connection to the SQL db but I've verified connection.

Comment: I think you need to see how many records your returning. If your using Visual Studio you can put a breakpoint in at 'while (reader.HasRows)'. Then see how many you're getting.

Comment: I was able to get the results I was looking for based on the answer provided below. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things you should be aware of here:

**1.**

You should use `while (reader.HasRows)` in case your stored procedure returns multiple resultsets. In that case you have to **iterate** through the result sets. See [Retrieving Data Using a DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So, if `selectRecipe` returns multiple resultsets (I am assuming this is not the case), change your code to this:

```
while (reader.HasRows) 
{ 
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        returnedResult.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
    }

    reader.NextResult();
}
```

**2.**
If `selectRecipe` returns single result set, change the while loop to `if(){}`:

```
if(reader.HasRows) 
{ 
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        returnedResult.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
    }

}
```

**3.**
 I would probably use `using` to manage the connection better ([using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)) :

```
public Recipe SelectRecord(int id)
{
    Recipe returnedResult = new Recipe();

    using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        var dbCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.selectRecipe", dbConn);

        dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        dbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);

        dbConn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = dbCommand.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                returnedResult.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    return returnedResult;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, afzalulh! It makes perfect sense that my application was hanging. I assume that if I were to return multiple result sets, the while statement would continue to iterate until reader.NextResult() did not find any rows. Thanks again for the clarification and links!